# AngularJS $locationChangeStart never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very simple code using the $location service in angular which does not work.

```
angular.module("app",[]).run(function($rootScope) {
    var $offFunction = $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(e) {
      if (confirm("Are you sure")) 
        return $offFunction();
      return e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

I just want to confirm if the user wants to leave the page, but it won't work if I try to change the address in the bar or if I press the back button in the browser.

Here is the fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/5dnm2/19/

Comment: whats is the `$offFunction()`?

Comment: If you enter a new URL in the address bar then the application does not know that the URL is about change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add $location for initialization provider. 
Visit http://jsfiddle.net/5dnm2/41/

`run(function($rootScope, $location) {...})`

Comment: Ok, that works, but it doesn't serve the purpose I wanted. This only shows the confirm dialog when loading the page. I wanted to show the confirm when the user is leaving the page (like using the event window.onbeforeunload on plain javascript). What i want actually is this code to run when the user clicks the back button in the browser, but couldn't make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand You correctly, You can try to equal urls:

`$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        if (next !== current) {
            var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page');
            if (!answer) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });`